# EL on DataTable Footer not showing

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm working with a DataTable, and I'm having some trouble displaying a value from an `EL` in the footer. I have made a simplified version of my `xhtml` that still reproduces the error.

If I do the `p:dataTable` like this it all works:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myMB.items}" var="item">
    <p:column headerText="Value" footerText="Value">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.value}">
            <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I get this as a result:

[image: Static Footer]

The footer shows just fine. And then I try it with `EL`, changing the column definition like this:

```
<p:column headerText="Value" footerText="#{3 + 11}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.value}">
        <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

And it evaluates my expression, I get this as a result:

[image: Simple EL footer]

It shows the correct value `14` in the footer. But when I try to use a value from my model, it doesn't show. See the example:

**Code**:

```
<p:column headerText="Value" footerText="#{item.value}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.value}">
        <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

**Output**:

[image: Model EL Footer]

And I have tried to do the footer in different ways. Not a single attempt worked.

Is there a correct way to do this? In the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf) it seems to work just fine.

I am using **PrimeFaces 3.3.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was lack of attention.

I failed to realize that I have multiple column values for a single footer. And since JSF can't decide on a single value, it shows nothing.

Shortly after I posted this the answer came to me. I tried to define a single value on my `ManagedBean` to use as footer, and it work just fine.

Again, there's nothing wrong with JSF and/or PrimeFaces, it was just lack of logical thinking from my part.

It works on the showcase, because it shows subtables that actually do have a footer for each value.